# StatefulWidget.createState must return a subtype of State<${widget.runtimeType}>

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, flutter-dependencies, dart-null-safety

I just opened flutter for the first time in a week and didnt change my code for my app in the entire week. Now I'm getting this weird flutter state error that I have never gotten before. Weirdly, it doesnt happen on one screen (with the same logic) but on the other one. Here is the code for the screen:

```
class AskSomellierStep4Screen extends StatefulWidget {
  const AskSomellierStep4Screen({
    Key? key,
    required this.stepDescription,
    required this.wineOrMeal,
    required this.mealVSWine,
    required this.selectedCuisine,
  }) : super(key: key);

  final String wineOrMeal;
  final String stepDescription;
  final bool mealVSWine;
  final String selectedCuisine;

  @override
  State<AskSomellierStep4Screen> createState() =>
      _AskSomellierStep4ScreenState();
}

class _AskSomellierStep4ScreenState extends State<AskSomellierStep4Screen> {
  QueryDocumentSnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>? _selectedSnapshot;
  List<String> dataLabel = [
    'Home',
    'Search',
    'Account',
  ];
  late Future resultsLoaded;
  List<IconData> data = [
    CustomIcons.home,
    CustomIcons.search,
    CustomIcons.user,
  ];

  getResults() async {
    var data = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection(widget.wineOrMeal)
        .where('type', isEqualTo: widget.selectedCuisine)
        .get();
    setState(() {
      allResults = data.docs;
    });
    filterResultsList();
    return data.docs;
  }

  List allResults = [];

  List filteredResults = [];

  onSearchChanged() {
    print(searchController.text);
    filterResultsList();
  }

  filterResultsList() {
    var showResults = [];

    if (searchController.text != '') {
      // we have a search parameter
      for (var searchSnapshot in allResults) {
        var name = searchSnapshot['name'].toLowerCase();

        if (name.contains(searchController.text.toLowerCase())) {
          showResults.add(searchSnapshot);
        }
      }
    } else {
      // we do not have a search parameter
      showResults = List.from(allResults);
    }
    setState(() {
      filteredResults = showResults;
    });
  }

  TextEditingController searchController = TextEditingController();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    searchController.addListener(onSearchChanged);
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    searchController.removeListener(onSearchChanged);
    searchController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  void didChangeDependencies() {
    super.didChangeDependencies();
    resultsLoaded = getResults();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).scaffoldBackgroundColor,
      body: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: [
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
              left: 35,
              top: 25,
            ),
            child: Stack(
              children: [
                Container(
                  height: 35,
                  width: 320,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
                  ),
                ),
                child: ListView.builder(
                dragStartBehavior: DragStartBehavior.down,
                scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                itemCount: filteredResults.length,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) => widget.mealVSWine
                    ? PrefInformationCardWine(
                        snapShotDocument: filteredResults[index],
                        cardColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                        isSelected:
                            filteredResults[index] == _selectedSnapshot,
                        onSelected: () {
                          setState(() {
                            _selectedSnapshot = filteredResults[index];
                          });
                        },
                      )
                    : PrefInformationCardMeal(
                        snapShotDocument: filteredResults[index],
                        cardColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                        isSelected:
                            filteredResults[index] == _selectedSnapshot,
                        onSelected: () {
                          setState(() {
                            _selectedSnapshot = filteredResults[index];
                          });
                        },
                      ),
              ),
                ...
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

the error causing widget is ListView() and this is the error I'm redirected to in the flutter framework
I have no idea why this is happening since I didnt change anything. It works for the winescreen but it doesnt work for the meal screen. I would very much appreciate all help:)

---

```
═══════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════
The following assertion was thrown building NotificationListener<KeepAliveNotification>:
StatefulWidget.createState must return a subtype of State<PrefInformationCardMeal>

The createState function for PrefInformationCardMeal returned a state of type _PrefInformationCardWineState, which is not a subtype of State<PrefInformationCardMeal>, violating the contract for createState.
The relevant error-causing widget was
ListView
lib/…/ask_somellier_screens/step_4.dart:237
When the exception was thrown, this was the stack
#0      new StatefulElement.<anonymous closure>
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:4887
#1      new StatefulElement
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:4897
#2      StatefulWidget.createElement
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:758
...     Normal element mounting (33 frames)
#35     Element.inflateWidget
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:3813
#36     Element.updateChild
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:3547
#37     SliverMultiBoxAdaptorElement.updateChild
package:flutter/…/widgets/sliver.dart:1263
#38     SliverMultiBoxAdaptorElement.performRebuild.processElement
package:flutter/…/widgets/sliver.dart:1167
#39     SliverMultiBoxAdaptorElement.performRebuild
package:flutter/…/widgets/sliver.dart:1225
#40     SliverMultiBoxAdaptorElement.update
package:flutter/…/widgets/sliver.dart:1144
#41     Element.updateChild
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:3526
#42     ComponentElement.performRebuild
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:4824
#43     Element.rebuild
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:4525
#44     ProxyElement.update
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:5146
#45     Element.updateChild
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:3526
#46     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.update
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:6214
#47     Element.updateChild
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:3526
#48     RenderObjectElement.updateChildren
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:5817
#49     MultiChildRenderObjectElement.update
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:6366
#50     _ViewportElement.update
package:flutter/…/widgets/viewport.dart:237
#51     Element.updateChild
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:3526
#52     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.update
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:6214
#53     Element.updateChild
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:3526
#54     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.update
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:6214
#55     Element.updateChild
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:3526
#56     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.update
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:6214
#57     Element.updateChild
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:3526
#58     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.update
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:6214
#59     Element.updateChild
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:3526
#60     ComponentElement.performRebuild
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:4824
#61     StatefulElement.performRebuild
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:4969
#62     Element.rebuild
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:4525
#63     StatefulElement.update
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:5001
#64     Element.updateChild
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:3526
#65     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.update
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:6214
#66     Element.updateChild
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:3526
#67     ComponentElement.performRebuild
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:4824
#68     Element.rebuild
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:4525
#69     ProxyElement.update
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:5146
#70     Element.updateChild
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:3526
#71     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.update
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:6214
#72     Element.updateChild
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:3526
#73     ComponentElement.performRebuild
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:4824
#74     Element.rebuild
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:4525
#75     ProxyElement.update
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:5146
#76     Element.updateChild
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:3526
#77     ComponentElement.performRebuild
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:4824
#78     StatefulElement.performRebuild
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:4969
#79     Element.rebuild
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:4525
#80     StatefulElement.update
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:5001
#81     Element.updateChild
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:3526
#82     ComponentElement.performRebuild
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:4824
#83     Element.rebuild
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:4525
#84     ProxyElement.update
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:5146
#85     Element.updateChild
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:3526
#86     ComponentElement.performRebuild
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:4824
#87     Element.rebuild
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:4525
#88     StatelessElement.update
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:4875
#89     Element.updateChild
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:3526
#90     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.update
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:6214
#91     Element.updateChild
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:3526
#92     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.update
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:6214
#93     Element.updateChild
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:3526
#94     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.update
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:6214
#95     Element.updateChild
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:3526
#96     RenderObjectElement.updateChildren
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:5817
#97     MultiChildRenderObjectElement.update
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:6366
#98     Element.updateChild
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:3526
#99     ComponentElement.performRebuild
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:4824
#100    Element.rebuild
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:4525
#101    StatelessElement.update
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:4875
#102    Element.updateChild
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:3526
#103    ComponentElement.performRebuild
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:4824
#104    Element.rebuild
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:4525
#105    ProxyElement.update
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:5146
#106    Element.updateChild
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:3526
#107    ComponentElement.performRebuild
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:4824
#108    Element.rebuild
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:4525
#109    ProxyElement.update
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:5146
#110    Element.updateChild
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:3526
#111    RenderObjectElement.updateChildren
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:5817
#112    MultiChildRenderObjectElement.update
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:6366
#113    Element.updateChild
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:3526
#114    ComponentElement.performRebuild
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:4824
#115    StatefulElement.performRebuild
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:4969
#116    Element.rebuild
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:4525
#117    StatefulElement.update
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:5001
#118    Element.updateChild
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:3526
#119    ComponentElement.performRebuild
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:4824
#120    Element.rebuild
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:4525
#121    ProxyElement.update
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:5146
#122    Element.updateChild
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:3526
#123    ComponentElement.performRebuild
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:4824
#124    StatefulElement.performRebuild
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:4969
#125    Element.rebuild
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:4525
#126    StatefulElement.update
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:5001
#127    Element.updateChild
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:3526
#128    SingleChildRenderObjectElement.update
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:6214
#129    Element.updateChild
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:3526
#130    ComponentElement.performRebuild
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:4824
#131    Element.rebuild
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:4525
#132    ProxyElement.update
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:5146
#133    Element.updateChild
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:3526
#134    SingleChildRenderObjectElement.update
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:6214
#135    Element.updateChild
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:3526
#136    ComponentElement.performRebuild
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:4824
#137    StatefulElement.performRebuild
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:4969
#138    Element.rebuild
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:4525
#139    StatefulElement.update
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:5001
#140    Element.updateChild
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:3526
#141    ComponentElement.performRebuild
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:4824
...
```

---

PrefInformationCardMeal:

```
class PrefInformationCardMeal extends StatefulWidget {
  PrefInformationCardMeal({
    Key? key,
    required this.snapShotDocument,
    required this.cardColor,
    required this.isSelected,
    required this.onSelected,
  }) : super(key: key);

  DocumentSnapshot snapShotDocument;
  Color cardColor;
  bool isSelected;
  VoidCallback onSelected;

  @override
  State<PrefInformationCardWine> createState() =>
      _PrefInformationCardWineState();
}

class _PrefInformationCardMealState extends State<PrefInformationCardMeal> {
  Color backgroundColor(context, selected) {
    setState(() {
      if (widget.isSelected == true) {
        widget.cardColor = Theme.of(context).primaryColorLight;
      } else {
        widget.cardColor = Theme.of(context).primaryColor;
      }
    });
    return widget.cardColor;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
        bottom: 25,
      ),
      child: GestureDetector(
        onTap: widget.onSelected,
        child: Stack(
          children: [
            Container(
              height: 185,
              width: 320,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: backgroundColor(context, widget.isSelected),
                boxShadow: [
                  BoxShadow(
                    offset: const Offset(0, 4),
                    color: const Color(0xff000000).withOpacity(.25),
                  ),
                ],
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(
                  35,
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Positioned(
              left: 15,
              top: 15,
              child: Container(
                height: 155,
                width: 138,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(35),
                  image: DecorationImage(
                    image: NetworkImage(widget.snapShotDocument['url']),
                    fit: BoxFit.fitHeight,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Positioned(
              top: 15,
              left: 170,
              child: SizedBox(
                height: 15,
                width: 125,
                child: Text(
                  widget.snapShotDocument['name'],
                  style: GoogleFonts.poppins(
                    textStyle: TextStyle(
                      color: Theme.of(context).indicatorColor,
                      fontSize: 10,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    ),
                  ),
                  softWrap: true,
                  overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                  textAlign: TextAlign.right,
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Positioned(
              left: 257,
              top: 41,
              child: Text(
                'Cuisine',
                style: GoogleFonts.poppins(
                  textStyle: const TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.white,
                    fontSize: 9,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                  ),
                ),
                textAlign: TextAlign.right,
              ),
            ),
            Positioned(
              left: 170,
              top: 56,
              child: CuisineCard(
                wineCuisine: widget.snapShotDocument['type'],
                height: 25,
                width: 127,
                color: Theme.of(context).scaffoldBackgroundColor,
                fontSize: 9,
              ),
            ),
            Positioned(
              left: 271,
              top: 91,
              child: Text(
                'Price',
                style: GoogleFonts.poppins(
                  textStyle: TextStyle(
                    color: Theme.of(context).indicatorColor,
                    fontSize: 9,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Positioned(
              left: 170,
              top: 105,
              child: Container(
                height: 25,
                width: 125,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Theme.of(context).scaffoldBackgroundColor,
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(7),
                ),
                child: Center(
                  child: RichText(
                    text: TextSpan(
                      children: <TextSpan>[
                        TextSpan(
                          text: widget.snapShotDocument['rating'],
                          style: GoogleFonts.poppins(
                            textStyle: TextStyle(
                              color: Theme.of(context).primaryColorLight,
                              fontSize: 12,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Positioned(
              top: 145,
              left: 170,
              child: LearnMoreButton(
                wineDocument: widget.snapShotDocument,
                routeWidget:
                    FoodDetailScreen(mealDocument: widget.snapShotDocument),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

PrefInformationWineCard

```
class PrefInformationCardWine extends StatefulWidget {
  PrefInformationCardWine({
    Key? key,
    required this.snapShotDocument,
    required this.cardColor,
    required this.isSelected,
    required this.onSelected,
  }) : super(key: key);

  DocumentSnapshot snapShotDocument;
  Color cardColor;
  bool isSelected;
  VoidCallback onSelected;

  @override
  State<PrefInformationCardWine> createState() =>
      _PrefInformationCardWineState();
}

class _PrefInformationCardWineState extends State<PrefInformationCardWine> {
  Color backgroundColor(context, selected) {
    setState(() {
      if (widget.isSelected == true) {
        widget.cardColor = Theme.of(context).primaryColorLight;
      } else {
        widget.cardColor = Theme.of(context).primaryColor;
      }
    });
    return widget.cardColor;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
        bottom: 25,
      ),
      child: GestureDetector(
        onTap: widget.onSelected,
        child: Stack(
          children: [
            Container(
              height: 185,
              width: 320,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: backgroundColor(context, widget.isSelected),
                boxShadow: [
                  BoxShadow(
                    offset: const Offset(0, 4),
                    color: const Color(0xff000000).withOpacity(.25),
                  ),
                ],
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(
                  35,
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Positioned(
              left: 15,
              top: 15,
              child: Container(
                height: 155,
                width: 138,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(35),
                  image: DecorationImage(
                    image: NetworkImage(widget.snapShotDocument['url']),
                    fit: BoxFit.fitHeight,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Positioned(
              top: 15,
              left: 170,
              child: SizedBox(
                height: 15,
                width: 125,
                child: Text(
                  widget.snapShotDocument['name'],
                  style: GoogleFonts.poppins(
                    textStyle: TextStyle(
                      color: Theme.of(context).indicatorColor,
                      fontSize: 10,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    ),
                  ),
                  softWrap: true,
                  overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                  textAlign: TextAlign.right,
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Positioned(
              left: 257,
              top: 41,
              child: Text(
                'Cuisine',
                style: GoogleFonts.poppins(
                  textStyle: const TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.white,
                    fontSize: 9,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                  ),
                ),
                textAlign: TextAlign.right,
              ),
            ),
            Positioned(
              left: 170,
              top: 56,
              child: CuisineCard(
                wineCuisine: widget.snapShotDocument['use'][0],
                height: 25,
                width: 60,
                color: Theme.of(context).scaffoldBackgroundColor,
                fontSize: 9,
              ),
            ),
            Positioned(
              left: 236,
              top: 56,
              child: CuisineCard(
                wineCuisine: widget.snapShotDocument['use'][1],
                height: 25,
                width: 60,
                color: Theme.of(context).scaffoldBackgroundColor,
                fontSize: 9,
              ),
            ),
            Positioned(
              left: 271,
              top: 91,
              child: Text(
                'Price',
                style: GoogleFonts.poppins(
                  textStyle: TextStyle(
                    color: Theme.of(context).indicatorColor,
                    fontSize: 9,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Positioned(
              left: 170,
              top: 105,
              child: Container(
                height: 25,
                width: 125,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Theme.of(context).scaffoldBackgroundColor,
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(7),
                ),
                child: Center(
                  child: RichText(
                    text: TextSpan(
                      children: <TextSpan>[
                        TextSpan(
                          text: widget.snapShotDocument['rating'],
                          style: GoogleFonts.poppins(
                            textStyle: TextStyle(
                              color: Theme.of(context).primaryColorLight,
                              fontSize: 12,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Positioned(
              top: 145,
              left: 170,
              child: LearnMoreButton(
                wineDocument: widget.snapShotDocument,
                routeWidget:
                    WineDetailScreen(wineDocument: widget.snapShotDocument),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you past here the full error trace?

Comment: yes i added it as an edit

Comment: Show usage of all relevant widgets, and also of `PrefInformationCardMeal` and `PrefInformationCardWine`. I'm also recommend you removing all final variables from your State class, use getters instead, they return a new instance of the objects. Controllers instances should be created on initState, not direcly as class fields.

Comment: added it but could you rather explain where this error is coming from because ive never had it and i have no idea how to debug it and how should I use the getters?

Comment: Can you show the step_4 file on line 237 and around, where the error originates? The ListView.

Comment: Also, that call on DidChangeDependencies is not a good idea, it will call on every widget build ...

Comment: yes i added the listview.builder in the first code field